# display marker on google map using angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Inside ioanic angularjs app I'm trying to display some location on google map. I'm rendering google and successfully center map using lat and lon but I cannot display marker on that exact location. 
Here's the code
View

```
<ion-view title="Location" ng-controller="LocationDetailController as vm">
<ion-content class="has-header">        
    <ui-gmap-google-map draggable="true" center="vm.map.center" zoom="vm.map.zoom" options="options">
        <ui-gmap-markers models="vm.marker" coords="'self'"  fit='true' icon="'icon'">
    </ui-gmap-google-map>   
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and inside LocationDetailController

```
...
vm.map = {
            center: {                           
                        latitude: vm.details.Latitude,
                        longitude: vm.details.Longitude
                    },
                    zoom: 13
            };
vm.marker = {                       
                latitude: vm.details.Latitude,
                longitude: vm.details.Longitude
            };
...
```

what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things missing.

The first is that the markers directive is expecting an array and is prepared to handle many markers, even if you are only using it for one marker the value passed into models attribute needs to be an array.

Secondly each marker (even if there is only one) needs a unique ID in the model object for that marker.

updated code:

```
$scope.vm.markers = [{
    id : 99,
    latitude: 43.67023,
    longitude: -79.38676
}];
```

[Here is a working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NgU1kiP5nJsdXLzUBp4U?p=preview)